# Reg. date format issue in json with jqgrid

Tags: json, jqgrid

I'm using jqgrid and have columns that display date but from the server the date comes in json format as below,

```
"CommentedDate": "\/Date(1304324941000+0530)\/"
```

How I can display the date correctly in MM/dd/yyyy format?

Vijaya Anand

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use [predefined formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter#predefined_format_types) `'date'` and jqGrid 4.0 it should work automatically. Try for example with the following properties for the column having the date:

```
formatter:'date', formatoptions: {newformat:'m/d/Y'}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it is coming as NaN/NaN/NaN.

Comment: @Vijaya Anand: Do you use jqGrid **4.0.0**?

Comment: sorry for not mentioning that it is 3.8.2.

Comment: @Oleg: Is there any issues may come if I do an upgrade to 4.0?

Comment: @Vijaya Anand: I don't understend whether you have success after update from 3.8.2 to 4.0.0? If you **really can't** update to the new version you can fix the problem if you replace in the `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` of 3.8.2 the text `/^\/Date((([-+])?[0-9]+)(([-+])([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2}))?)\/$/` to `/^\/Date\((([-+])?[0-9]+)(([-+])([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2}))?\)\/$/`.

Comment: @Vijaya Anand: In 4.0 many known bugs are fixed. The only thing which you should take in consideration that `jquery.searchFilter.js` was rewriten. So if you included if explicitly you should remove it. The look of the Searching dialog is now another, but it should be compatible. I prefere to use the last version from `http://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/tree/master` where some bugs are fixed. For example are fixed bug, that "Add" button in the Navigator can be used only once. But if you use `recreateForm:true` option the problem not exist.

Comment: @Oleg: I replaced the text and that squashed the bug, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the NaN/NaN/NaN issue for date-field by manually altering the jquery.jqgrid.src.js (4.5.2).
In my case, the json response would return date in an 'ISO1860Long'. It used to work till the 4.1.2 jqgrid version

Search for "parseDate" function; goto the line after :

```
if( opts.masks.hasOwnProperty(format) ) { format = opts.masks[format]; }
if(date && date != null) {
```

and add the below if check :

```
if(date.constructor === Number) {
  if(String(format).toLowerCase() == "u") {
    date = date*1000;
  }
  timestamp = new Date(date);
} else
```

before the existing :

```
if( !isNaN( date - 0 ) && String(format).toLowerCase() === "u") {
```

you can translate the changes to jquery.jqgrid.min.js  yourself IF needed